# How can i open pip file codes to read?

Tags: python, pip, gzip

I'm trying to check how the (pip black) is written and would love to read its code but having trouble.

I downloaded the file from browser but its on gz format and when I try to open it on VSCode I get cryptic lines like

```
���nc�Onlyfinnaly.log
```

What am i supposed to do?

I tried downloading the pip directly on VSCode and checking the commands avaliable also opening it on text editor but its no help. I was expecting to be able to read the lines of codes that are written on the pip file

Comment: `pip` is nothing but a python file. Open the file itself which is located in your `PATH`. The file is named `pip.py`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should take you to the source code:
[image]
Here's the link: https://github.com/psf/black